# REST RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, http-headers

How do I correct an inquiry? Comes back only 200 OK status without a body.

My code:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add("Authorization", sessionId);
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",
           headers);            
   ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url,
            HttpMethod.POST, entity , String.class);
```

error:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Cannot extract response: no Content-Type found

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I understand how to make it         HttpStatus httpStatus = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                getEntity(sessionId), null).getStatusCode();